# Biblioshiny doesn't read "categories" in the bib data

Tags: r, user-interface, rstudio, analysis

I exported bibliomatric data from WoS including all the info available. Looking at the .bib file you can see that all the papers have the category information as " Web-of-Science-Categories  = {Computer Science, Artificial Intelligence; Neurosciences}".

However, when I load the data with biblioshiny everything goes well except this. In fact, it says "Completely missing".

Any idea why this occur and how to solve it?

Not sure what steps to take.

Comment: I tried editing "Web-of-Science-Categories = {Computer Science, Artificial Intelligence; Neurosciences}" to "Category = {Computer Science, Artificial Intelligence; Neurosciences}", but nothing has changed.